# Distributed Builds in XCode 4.5?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, distributed

I'd like to enable "Distributed Builds" so my Mac can farm building out to other idle Macs in the office to speed up build times. Apparently there used to be a "Distributed Builds" option in Preferences in older versions of XCode, as can be seen by the screenshot near the top of this blog:

http://blog.mundue.net/2010/12/distributed-builds/

But no such thing in the latest XCode. Is Distributed Builds even an option anymore, in XCode 4.5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Distributed builds was removed in Xcode 4.3 I believe. Shame because it was a great feature!